# Cannot update to Window 10, despite my reservations year ago

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10-upgrade

From what I've been told, to get a free copy of Windows 10 you had to reserve it before July 29th, 2016. I reserved it well before the deadline, and I've been told that the reservation was successful. Today I decided to upgrade to Windows 10, since everything "is alright". But it doesn't work for me, for whatever reason.

1. Clicking on the upgrade notification icon opens a window with nothing that leads to upgrading in it. I can check my PC before upgrading, apparently, but it doesn't work for me, saying that the report isn't available right now but "don't worry wait a little bit more".
2. Using the `MediaCreationTool` for upgrading doesn't work either - it requires a key, which I of course don't have.

What can I do?

Comment: As far as I remember, you still had to change before the deadline.

Comment: I think you had to at least start the upgrade before the deadline ran out almost a year ago, but the reservation stage might have worked.  If it did then you can skip the key entering stage in the Media Creation Tool method and it should activate automatically.  In your case though I'd take a full backup of your old system to restore to, just in case you are too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All upgrades needed to be completed by July 29 2016.

- Do I still qualify for the free upgrade offer if I've already downloaded Windows 10 to a USB drive, but haven't yet upgraded my device?

  > All upgrades must have completed and reached the "Welcome" screen by 11:59 PM UTC-10 (Hawaii) on July 29; this is one worldwide point in time.
- Is the Windows 10 free upgrade offer still available?

  > The Windows 10 free upgrade through the Get Windows 10 (GWX) app ended on July 29, 2016.
- How do I get Windows 10?

  > Windows 10 will continue to be available for purchase, either on a device or as a full version of the software.

([Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12435/windows-10-upgrade-faq))